# Generating a query to compare head-to-head stats

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to generate a query to see the win percentage between two players when they are a team captain against one another in a game.

I created the schema on sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2f8c/1

The table (called games) and it's relevant fields are:

```
gameID | pID | pWin | pLose | pCaptain
 100      1     0       1        1
 100      2     1       0        1
```

If a player wins a game, pWin is set to 1 and pLose is set to 0, while the loser will get a 0 in pWin and a 1 in pLose. If they were the team captain that picked teams that game, pCaptain is set to 1.

I'd like to be able to enter two player ID's and get a win percentage. I've been tinkering with some queries for a little while but the query involved exceeds my knowledge of SQL.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT p1.sumwin/(p1.sumwin + p2.sumwin)*100 as p1,
       p2.sumwin/(p1.sumwin + p2.sumwin)*100 as p2
FROM
      (SELECT pID, sum(pWin) sumWin
         FROM games
        WHERE  pCaptain = 1
        GROUP BY pID) p1,
      (SELECT pID, sum(pWin) sumWin
         FROM games
        WHERE  pCaptain = 1
        GROUP BY pID) p2
WHERE p1.pid = 1 AND
      p2.pid = 2
```

or I didnt understood you (in that case sorry).

@MotiveKyle any better now?

```
SELECT (sum(p1.pWin)/(sum(p1.pWin) + sum(p2.pWin)))*100 p1Win,
        (sum(p2.pWin)/(sum(p1.pWin) + sum(p2.pWin)))*100 p2Win
FROM
      (SELECT pID, pWin, gameID
         FROM games
        WHERE  pCaptain = 1) p1,
      (SELECT pID, pWin, gameID
         FROM games
        WHERE  pCaptain = 1) p2
WHERE p1.gameID = p2.gameID AND
      p1.pID = 1 AND
      p2.pID = 2
```

**Basicly it says:**

1. collect all games from all players in p1
2. collect all games from all players in p2
3. join subviews p1 and p2 by game
4. filter result to games played by player1 and player2
5. sumarize all wins from both players and calculate percentages.

Comment: That's very close. Initially, I thought it worked, but it seems to just count the number of times each person has won as captain, but not against the other player. For example, each team can only have one captain, so if there are 3 games where Player1 is captain of team 1, and Player2 is captain of team 2, and Player1 wins 2 out of those 3 games, he would have a 66% win percentage.